How to verify user's email thats retrieved from using Twitter/X free plan?
i have been testing out Twitter/X free plan found on this page:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/twitter-api
I have successfully implemented NextJs Auth (Login With Twitter) in my app.
When i use this in one of my components:
 const session = await getServerSession(authConfig);
This is the user data i am getting from session:

email
image
name

Now, email and name i am sending to my backend web service so I can also register the user in my own database. But here is the problem:
My frontend app, cannot just so easily send any email with any name to my backend API and guarantee that the user is correct. What im basically saying is that someone can use Postman, and manually create API request to my backend and in-turn create the user with sort of wrong credentials.
Is it possible that i can prevent that trough my own backend? To somehow validate the user using twitter?
I had an idea to actually send a a verification email to the email I got from twitter, and prompt the user to verify it, and this i can say that it worked.
But if i had no option of email verification, how would I validate that data i receive for the user that login-ed to my website using twitter is valid on my backend, so i can create a user for my database?
I explained this in details.

You would not send the email address from the frontend in the first place; instead, you would only send the access token that you got during the login process, to the server - and then use that to make an API call from the server side, to fetch user details such as the email address, from TXwitter.

I havent received any access tokens? Where can i find that? I just those three:
email,
image,
name
from a session

Don't know, you'd have to check the documentation of the package you used to implement this.
